# SQL for a query with several input IDs, how to get the first 5 results for each ID

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query that accepts several IDs as filters in a WHERE clause.
it's formatted something like this:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.VOLUMETRY, b.ANNOY_DISTANCE
FROM PRODUCT a
JOIN RECOMMENDATIONS b on a.ID = b.ID
WHERE a.ID in ('0001','0002', ...., '0099')
ORDER BY b.ANNOY_DISTANCE
```

Now this query can return several thousand results for each ID, but I only need the first 5 for each ID after ordering them by the ANNOY_DISTANCE column. The rest aren't needed and would only slow post-processing of the data.

How can I change this so that the query result only gives the first 5 rows for each ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions, which you can filter using a `QUALIFY` clause:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.VOLUMETRY, r.ANNOY_DISTANCE
FROM PRODUCT p JOIN
     RECOMMENDATIONS r
     ON p.ID = r.ID
WHERE a.ID in ('0001','0002', ...., '0099')
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.ID ORDER BY r.ANNOY_DISTANCE) <= 5
ORDER BY r.ANNOY_DISTANCE;
```

Notice that I changed your table aliases to be meaningful abbreviations for the table names.  That is a best practice.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! This is exactly what I needed. Cheers!